# EF Core Add() only adds the last element to an ICollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to add an element to an ICollection object in EF Core 5. But only the last element remains on the list.
As an example, When a student submits an answer, I want to add him to the Participants of the exam(A). It works as it should. But when the same person submits another exam(B). His records are lost from the previous exam(A).

Here is my code.

SubmitExam Method in ExamController.cs

```
 [HttpPost("submit")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<GetExamDTO>> SubmitExam(GetExamDTO getExamDTO)
    {
        var username = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
        var user = await _userManager.Users
            .Where(u => u.UserName == username)
            .Include(u => u.ParticipatedExams)
            .ThenInclude(er => er.Exam)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (user == null)
            return Unauthorized("Invalid User");

        var exam = await _dbContext.Exams
            .Where(e => e.Id == getExamDTO.Id)
            .Include(e => e.Creator)
            .Include(e => e.Participants)
            .Include(exam => exam.Questions)
            .ThenInclude(question => question.Options)
            .AsSplitQuery()
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

        if (exam == null)
            return BadRequest("Invalid Exam Id");
        if (!exam.SubmissionEnabled)
            return BadRequest("Exam is over. You are too late.");
        double marksObtained = 0;
        double negativeMarksObtained = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i != getExamDTO.Questions.Count(); ++i)
        {
            var question = exam.Questions.ElementAt(i);

            if (question.CorrectAnswerText == getExamDTO.Questions[i].ProvidedAnswer.Text)
            {
                marksObtained += question.Marks;
            }
            else
            {
                marksObtained -= exam.NegativeMarks;
                negativeMarksObtained -= exam.NegativeMarks;
            }
        }
        var participatedFromExam = exam.Participants.Where(u => u.Id == user.Id)
            .SingleOrDefault();
        var participatedFromUser = user.ParticipatedExams
            .Where(er => er.ExamId == exam.Id)
            .SingleOrDefault();

        System.Console.WriteLine("Submit" + participatedFromExam);
        if (participatedFromExam == null && participatedFromUser == null) // If user sits for the first time, count him as new.
        {
            exam.Participants.Add(user); // Participants gets empty for every exam except the last submitted one. It fried my brain.
            ++exam.Attendees;
            if (await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync() > 0)
                System.Console.WriteLine("Added submission");
            var result = new ExamResult
            {
                Exam = exam,
                Score = marksObtained
            };

            user.ParticipatedExams.Add(result);
            await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
        }
        var examDto = examToDto(exam);

        examDto.Participated = true;
        examDto.MarksObtained = marksObtained;
        examDto.Questions = getExamDTO.Questions;
        examDto.NewSubmission = true;
        examDto.NegativeMarks = negativeMarksObtained;
        return Ok(examDto);
    }
```

EntityUser.cs

```
public class EntityUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<ExamResult> ParticipatedExams { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastActive { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

Exam.cs

```
public class Exam
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Attendees { get; set; } = 0;
    public string CreatorId { get; set; }
    public EntityUser Creator { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public double TotalMarks { get; set; }
    public double NegativeMarks { get; set; }
    public bool SubmissionEnabled { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EntityUser> Participants { get; set; }
}
```

ExamResult.cs

```
public class ExamResult
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Exam Exam { get; set; }
    public Guid ExamId { get; set; }
    public double Score { get; set; }
}
```

GetExamDTO.cs

```
public class GetExamDTO
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Attendees { get; set; } = 0;
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string CreatorId { get; set; }
    public string Creator { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }
    public double TotalMarks { get; set; }
    public double MarksObtained { get; set; }
    public double NegativeMarks { get; set; }
    public bool SubmissionEnabled { get; set; }
    public bool Participated { get; set; }
    public bool NewSubmission { get; set; }
    public List<QuestionDTO> Questions { get; set; }
    public List<ParticipantDTO> Participants { get; set; }
}
```

I will appreciate any help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Configure the many to many relationship between `Exam` and `EntityUser` properly. Replace `ICollection<EntityUser> Participants` by `ICollection<ExamResult> Participants`.

Comment: This is exactly what I did and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fix the Examresult class by adding UserId

```
public partial class ExamResult
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

 public int? UserId { get; set; }
 public virtual EntityUser User { get; set; }

    public Guid ExamId { get; set; }
    public virtual Exam Exam { get; set; }
  
    public double Score { get; set; }
}

public partial class EntityUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<ExamResult> ParticipatedExams { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastActive { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

you can try to add fluent api to your db context

```
 public virtual DbSet<ExamResult> ExamResults { get; set; }

.....

modelBuilder.Entity<ExamResult>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(d => d.User)
                    .WithMany(p => p.ParticipatedExams)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
                    
            });
```

and code

```
var result = new ExamResult
            {
                UserId=user.Id,
                ExamId = exam.Id,
                Score = marksObtained
            };
 _dbContext.ExamResults.Add(result)
await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Can you post Question and GetExamDto classes pls?

Comment: There is only one Exam with a specified Id. Why do I need to make it into a List?

Comment: Sure I did it  .

Comment: Sorry you are right. But try to remove as split query.

Comment: Removing AsSplitQuery() didn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: It didn't work either, unfortunately. However, The particaped exams in the user object saves them perfectly. It's only the Exam that doesn't hold participates accurately

Comment: @NeonX I updated my answer , pls try again

Comment: I added DbSet<ExamResults> to the context and followed your answer. exam.participants still only holds the last added value. BUT your answer gave me a new(and I think a better one) idea. I can replace participates with examresults in Exam entity.

Comment: @NeonX You have to make a database migration after the class changing

Comment: You have to add fluent api or attributes. What are you using?

Comment: I was able to fix it . You really tried to help me. I appreciate your help. Thanks !

Comment: Sorry.I can't even upvote you. It's only my second post ever. I did what I said. Changed Participants from  EntityUsers to ExamResults and renamed it to SubmittedAnswers

Comment: I marked it as answer because it helped me rethink about the entire thing. Thanks